# Completion of the set of subsets with half volume.

Tags: measure-theory, completion

Let $X$ be a measure space with finite $|X|=\int_X1$ and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Under what condition on $X$ and $f$ does there exist a subset $Y \subset X$ satisfying the following?

1. $|Y|=|X|/2$
2. $\int_Yf=\inf_{|Z|=|X|/2}\{\int_Zf\}$

To prove this kind of statement, we need some completeness of the set $\{Z \subset X  \ | \ |Z|=|X|/2\}$, but I don't know how to get such a completion.

Comment: You are basically trying to arrive at the notion of the median in a mildly convoluted fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the least real r such that the measure of the set Y of those points in X that map to something below r is one half the measure of X.

Answer (score -1):

The "completeness" you ask for is essentially compactness in the weak* topology.  Let $S\subset L^\infty(X)$ consist of all functions $g$ such that $\int g=|X|/2$ and $0\leq g\leq 1$.  This set is weak*-compact, so for any $f\in L^1(X)$, the functional $g\mapsto \int fg$ is must have a minimum on $S$.  Furthermore, by Krein-Milman, this minimum must be achieved at some extreme point of $S$.  If $X$ is atomless, it is easy to see that any extreme point of $S$ must be a characteristic function.

(The hypothesis of atomlessness is necessary, of course, since otherwise there might not be any subset of $X$ at all with half measure.)